# Multilanguage site randomly changes language

Tags: asp.net, .net, globalization

I have started to notice something weird. I use standard Asp.net App_GlobalResources to server site (.Net 4) according users browser language and have 5 different languages. Most of time time it works fine. But some times (i suspect under heavy load) default language randomly changes to one of the languages available

Web.config is:

```
<globalization culture="auto:en-GB" uiCulture="auto:en-GB" />
```

Anyone experienced it?

UPDATE: it looks like it picks first language resource from alphabetically sorted list of language resources

Comment: I actually have a similar problem, but for us, it wasn't choosing the first language in the list, but if someone logged in from say Poland, an random english user would also get Polish on the next request! We haven't been able to solve this yet...

Answer (score 1):

try this in web.config

```
<globalization enableClientBasedCulture="true" culture="en-GB" uiCulture="en-GB" 
requestEncoding="windows-1256" responseEncoding="windows-1256" 
fileEncoding="windows-1256"/>
```

and here [ASP.NET Localization: Working with Multi-Language Web Applications](http://www.devproconnections.com/content1/topic/multi-language-app-142880/catpath/aspnet2)

Comment: sorry but this is nothing to do with my question. enableClientBasedCulture="true" culture="en-GB" uiCulture="en-GB" is same as culture="auto:en-GB" uiCulture="auto:en-GB". My problem is (at times) culture being read from first available resx regardless client's preference

Comment: You also need the enableClientBasedCulture="”true”". Look in here for more info about it:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.configuration.globalizationsection.enableclientbasedculture.aspx